# Filter based on NotNull criteria

Tags: java

So I'm trying to filter out the jsonResponse based on some keys ... return that block if it has all the provided keys

The pseudo code is like this:

```
public Object filterSomething(String key1, String key2, String key3){


    for (Map<Object, Object> singleBlock : (List<Map<Object, Object>> someJsonResponse)){
        if (singleBock.IncludesAllNotNullKeys) {
            return singleBlock
        }
    }

}
```

Note that any `key` could be Null (which is specified by the end-user), in that case I'm gonna filter the result based on the ones that are not null.

clearly I can check the check which ones are NotNull and then have multiple for loops (but that looks very messy! ) ... something like this:

```
public Object filterSomething(String key1, String key2, String key3){

    if (key1 != Null && key2 != Null && key3 != Null) {
        for (Map<Object, Object> singleBlock : (List<Map<Object, Object>> someJsonResponse)){
            if (singleBock.IncludesAllKeys()) {
                return singleBlock
            }
        }
    }

    if (key1 != Null && key2 != Null) {
        for (Map<Object, Object> singleBlock : (List<Map<Object, Object>> someJsonResponse)){
            if (singleBock.IncludesBothKeys()) {
                return singleBlock
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Is there any suggestion on how to handle this case properly?

Comment: Which json library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would just check the null in the logic when you check if a single block contains that keys: `singleBock.IncludesAllNotNullKeys`

The method could look like this:

```
private boolean includesAllNotNullKeys(Object singleBlock, String key1, String key2, String key3) {
    boolean check1 = key1 == null || singleBlock.contains(key1);
    boolean check2 = key2 == null || singleBlock.contains(key2);
    boolean check3 = key3 == null || singleBlock.contains(key3);
    return check1 && check2 && check3;
}
```

Of course, this is tailored exactly to your problem. For a more reusable, generic way you could handle the keys as var-args or `List<String>` and the method could iterate and break accordingly.